# Find the derivative of $y=\sin^2(3x)$

Tags: calculus, differential

Our instructor had given us an equation and we should get the derivative of it. But even him, he is confused what to do (funny college instructor) if we should use identities before deriving or either derive it early.
Here is the equation:

$$y = \sin^2(3x)$$.

Since the answer of two ways are different. What should be the correct way?

Comment: For fun, let's do it an odd way. Note that from $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2 t$ we obtain $\sin^2(3x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(6x))$. Differentiate. We get $3\sin(6x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You get $y' = 6 \sin(3x) \cos(3x)$ as result using chain rule and product rule. And if you derive that equation on two ways, you will always get the same result since the function is differentiable on $\mathbb R$. If your instructor says something else he is simply wrong.

Comment: It would be bad if the result would depend on the way the calculation is done.

Comment: This is right, but it could be further simplified to $3 \sin(6x)$. Looks nicer that way.

Comment: Yeah, probably. But I'm not very into this trigonometric formula stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Use the chain rule!

If $h(x) = f(g(x))$
then
$h'(x) = f(g(x))*g'(x)$

but it appears that you will have to perform the chain rule **twice!**

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Apply it twice and you will have that:

$$y' = 2\sin(3x)\cos(3x)3 = 6\sin(3x)cos(3x)$$

We used here that:

$f(x) = x^2 \implies f'(x) = 2x$

$g(x) = \sin(x) \implies g'(x) = cos(x)$

$h(x) = ax \implies h'(x) = a$

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method

$y=\sin^23x\\
\implies y=\frac{(1-\cos 6x)}{2}\\
\text{Now apply chain rule} \\
\frac{dy}{dx}=(-(-\sin 6x)\cdot6)/2=3\sin6x$

Comment: So this                                                                                                            $$y'=3sin(6x)$$ and $$y'=6sin(3x)cos(3x)$$ are the same?

Comment: Yes.you can rearrange $6\sin 3x\cos 3x$ to $3\times 2\sin 3x\cos 3x$ to $3\sin 6x$ :)

Answer (score 0):

What identities are you referring to?

I will assume you are talking about the identity $\sin^2(3x) = 1 - \cos^2 (3x)$.

This says to you that $\sin^2(3x)$ is *equal* to $1 - \cos^2 (3x)$: so, directly deriving $\sin^2(3x)$ yelds the same result as deriving $1 - \cos^2 (3x)$.

If fact:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2(3x) = 2 \sin(3x) \cos(3x) \cdot 3 = 6 \sin(3x) \cos(3x)$$

as well as

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( 1 - \cos^2(3x) \right) = \left[ - 2 \cos(3x) \right] \left( - \sin (3x) \right) \cdot 3 = 6 \sin(3x) \cos(3x)$$

Your instructor should always obtain this result.

As others mentioned, in both cases you must obviously apply two times the chain rule for $[f(g(x))]^2 = \sin^2(3x)$ or $[f(g(x))]^2 = \cos^2(3x)$, the first time for the 2nd power of sine (or cosine) and the second time for $3x$.